# ICloud's photo stream API?

Tags: macos, icloud

Is there any API that would help me to extract pictures from my iCloud's photo stream on Mac ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

I believe the answer at the moment is not officially. The [iCloud for Developers](http://developer.apple.com/icloud/index.php) API would be the straightforward way to do it. But every description I've read of it talks only about "Documents" and "Key/Value Data": photos and Photo Stream are conspicuous by their absence. (I don't have access to read the API docs; someone with Mac or iOS developer access could verify this.)

I've noticed that on my Mac syncing via Photo Stream, the photos I took on my iPhone and sent to iCloud are showing up in /Users/nelson/Pictures/iPhoto Library/Masters/. Presumably this is the local cache iPhoto maintains. Not a formal API, but possibly a quick and dirty way to get ahold of the images.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I have found another local cached folder with the pictures and developed an application to manage it (http://www.petits-suisses.ch).

Comment: Thanks! For Lightroom, is there any reason not to just set the cache directory itself as a watched folder and have Lightroom pick up photos from there?

Comment: No, for 3 reasons: 1. Lightroom wants to start with a clean folder 2. Lightroom deletes pictures after retrieving 3. Watched folders cannot look into subfolders what here the case is.

Comment: Where did you find it Laurent?